# Android game Multi Screen Resolution

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, resolution, aspect-ratio

If I design a game for 3:2 screen ratio, and another device has 4:3 or 16:9, how can I make the game look the same? I can scale the resolution for same aspect ratio, but when it's different what can I do?

Comment: Is this question for UI?

Comment: No, i am making a classic block breaker game and i want to think of the grid, block size, walls size and all that and when the aspect ratio is different from what i designed it there is a blank space on the edges.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to design your game with biggest screen possible (3:2 i think), and then check it with the smallest screen(16:9 i think). if your game is portrait then scale when height changed and if your game is landscape then scale your game when width changes.